# Gelato automate frequency of execution on mainnet

Tags: blockchain, gelato, automate

while using a Resolver contract on Gelato Automate, what's the frequency of Gelato calling the verify function? I did a test in goerli, and it's calling the function every 20sec. How about mainnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gelato checks your resolver contract every block, approximately every 15 seconds on the mainnet.

Gelato automate docs can be found [here](https://docs.gelato.network/developer-services/automate)